# Select distinct current and previous columns from a sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table like so

```
   Id  |Name    |Status |   Rate |  Method  |ModifiedTime             |ModifiedBy
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1  |Recipe1 |  0    |    30  |   xyz    | 2016-07-26 14:55:57.977 |     A
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2  |Recipe1 |  0    |    30  |   abc    | 2016-07-26 14:56:18.123 |     A
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    3  |Recipe1 |  1    |    30  |   xyz    | 2016-07-26 14:57:50.180 |     b
```

I would like to select only the changes and wanted to show what the value was previously and what it is currently accompanied by who changed it.  The final outcome will be as follows. I am using SQL Server 2014.

```
Item    | Before |  After |ModifiedTime             | ModifiedBy
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Method  |  xyz   |  Abc   | 2016-07-26 14:56:18.123 |   A
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Status  |  0     |  1     | 2016-07-26 14:57:50.180 |   b
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Method  |  Abc   |  xyz   | 2016-07-26 14:57:50.180 |   b
```

Comment: I see you changed your output. Did my query work for you?

Comment: Yes it did beautifully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without dynamic SQL this is the best I could do.
I'm assuming that you are grouping changes by `Name`. If `Name` can change it should be removed of the partition by and added to the items subquery and to the `case`. You can try it [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/517195/show-changes-over-time)

```
select item, 
       case item
         when 'Status' then cast(prevStatus as varchar)
         when 'Rate' then cast(prevRate as varchar)
         when 'Method' then prevMethod
         end as Before, 
       case item
         when 'Status' then cast(Status as varchar)
         when 'Rate' then cast(Rate as varchar)
         when 'Method' then Method
         end as After,
         ModifiedTime,
         ModifiedBy
  from (
    select Status,
           lag(Status) over (partition by Name order by id) prevStatus,
           Rate,
           lag(Rate) over (partition by Name order by id) prevRate,
           Method,
           lag(Method) over (partition by Name order by id) prevMethod,
           ModifiedBy,
           ModifiedTime
      from t ) as t1 cross join  (select 'Status' as item union all 
                                  select 'Rate' as item union all 
                                  select 'Method' as item) items
where (item = 'Status' and Status <> prevStatus)
   or (item = 'Rate' and Rate <> prevRate)
   or (item = 'Method' and Method <> prevMethod)
order by ModifiedTime
```

**OUTPUT**

```
item   Before After ModifiedTime            ModifiedBy 
------ ------ ----- ----------------------- ---------- 
Method xyz    abc   2016-07-26 14:56:18.123 A          
Status 0      1     2016-07-26 14:57:50.180 b          
Method abc    xyz   2016-07-26 14:57:50.180 b
```

On the second row you'll see that ModifiedBy is `b` while you have `A`. I think is a typo.

Comment: Hi Yes it was a type and i have updated the question now.  The solution works but what if i have over 500 columns in a table.  Is there a way i can  do this dynamically?

Comment: @Abe Yes, with Dynamic sql querying sys. all_columns

Comment: Sorry can I have have a sample please.  Also the table we are starting with is a temporary table.

Comment: @Abe please post a new question with all the new information, referencing this question if you want.

Comment: I have posted a new question as your requested here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38617690/dynamically-select-distinct-current-and-previous-columns-from-a-sql-table